# element border is moving on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I want right border to always be static.
At this moment, when I hover li element border-right is moving down 5px because of the border-top of 5px on hover.

HTML

```
<nav>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="link1">link1</a></li>
     <li><a href="link2">link2</a></li>
     <li><a href="link3">link3</a></li>             
     <li><a href="link4">link4</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
```

CSS

```
    nav li a {
    border-right: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
    }
    nav ul li:first-child a:hover {
        border-top:5px solid #d1e751;
    }
    nav ul li:nth-child(2) a:hover {
        border-top: 5px solid #F06B50;
    }
    nav ul li:nth-child(3) a:hover {
        border-top: 5px solid #eee;
    }
    nav ul li:last-child(4) a:hover {
        border-top: 5px solid #a8def4;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xfy6P/

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Just set an initial `border-top` property?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Xfy6P/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this at the bottom and it will fix it ^^, by adding padding-bottom on the hover it will compesate the extra pixels that the border top will add, its like 18 - 5 = 13 and the border right will remain the same

```
nav ul li a:hover{
    padding-bottom:13px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set Top border with background color of container
like

```
nav li a {
    border-right: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
    border-top: 5px solid [background-color];
    }
```

Comment: Or set the color to transparent.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Xfy6P/1/ - setting the initial border-top to white works. You could set it to transparent as well.

Comment: Thank you. But I would like to keep that moving effect if possible.

Comment: So what is your problem finally..?

Comment: I want right border to be static on hover, while keeping moving text effect.

Answer (score 0):

just added one property in your CSS code.

```
nav li a {
    border-top:5px solid transparent; /* using the transparent border to achieve the result*/
    border-right: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to leave the moving text effect on hover? I just want to fix the right border, make it static if possible.

Answer (score 0):

try by adding following code

```
nav ul li a{
        padding-top:23px;
    }
     nav ul li a:hover{
        padding-top:18px;
     }
```

Comment: Don't just paste code, give a little explanation so future users or current users with a little less knowledge can understand better your answer